# Toggle all layers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am using CSS buttons to toggle map layers in a leaflet.js environment. I have 25 layers. I would like to add 1 more button that will toggle ALL layers on/off. Here is the code I use for toggling the layers.

```
<div id="projects" class="layers" style="width: 400px; height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;">
 <a id="1" class="1" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="1" href="#1">1</a>
 <a id="2" class="2" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="2" href="#2">2</a>
 <a id="3" class="3" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="3" href="#3">3</a>
 <a id="4" class="4" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="4" href="#4">4</a>
 <a id="5" class="5" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="5" href="#5">5</a>
 <a id="6" class="6" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="6" href="#6">6</a>
<a id="7" class="7" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="7" href="#7">7</a>
<a id="25" class="25" data-control="layer" data-layer-level="" data-layer-name="25" href="#25">25</a>
</div>
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery then you can hide all the element under the layers div using

```
$('layers a').hide();
```

and show them again by using

```
$('layers a').show();
```

or you could add a class on the click such as "hide" that has a css of display:none and then just remove the class when you click to show the layers